# How to apply a style of a Button dynamically in WP 8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I have one WP 8.1 apps. I am following a complete MVVM design pattern. In the XAML code

```
 <Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="gameCanvas"         
         Width="{Binding CanvasWidth, 
                 Mode=TwoWay, 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ButtonItems, 
                             Mode=TwoWay,                            
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:Name="Dta">
             <Button x:Name="newsItemBtn"
                 Height="{Binding Height}"
                 Width="{Binding Width}"
                 Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle2}"
                 Content="{Binding Content}"
                 Command="{Binding                       
                           Path=DataContext.ButtonClickCommand,
                           ElementName=gameCanvas}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding Content}">
             </Button>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
 </Canvas>
```

But what I want is to assign the style of the button dynamically at runtime. 
I have three Button Style defined in the `GamePage.XAML.`

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" />
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle2" />
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle3" />
```

Now based on some value or some property on `ViewModel` i want to select the button Style 
I tried using a `converter`. But not much success.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At one point I needed to do the same thing and I just used a converter, that returned a named resource:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is bool && (bool)value)
    {
        return App.Current.Resources["ComplexProductTypeTemplate"];
    }
    return App.Current.Resources["SimpleProductTypeTemplate"];
}
```

I guess it could work the same way with resources identified by keys.

Comment: I tried that In the XAML  `Style="{Binding Path=DataContext.BtnStyle, Converter={StaticResource ButtonStyleConverter}}"`  but it does not work,

Comment: @Debhere - What exactly are you binding to that style (I mean the BtnStyle field - what is that)? Also, what happens in the converter itself?  
------>  
EDIT: Ok, I've just looked up how I used those converters. Are you sure you need to bind BtnStyle by that 'Path' attribute?

Comment: Yes that's required, however after some changes, Now I am able to hit the `ButtonStyleConverter` but `return App.Current.Resources["ButtonStyle3"];` throws Not found exception, I checked the Resources in debug, It does not contain any key, the value is Key.count = 0;

Comment: @Debhere - Yeah, that Path thing was just a hunch - I rarely use it and that was the only difference I could see :)  Anyway, I didn't notice you're adding the styles to a single page's resources. We have all the styles added to the app's global ResourceDictionary, so that's why I could find them in `App.Current.Resources`. To make the converter work for you, you'd have to somehow return something from the resources belonging to the page you're currently on. OR just add those three styles to the `<resources>` in the App.xaml ;D

Comment: Excellent, this is what I wanted. Its working, thanks. Setting those resources in the App.xaml does the trick.